# Python 3 command line arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to create a python script that'll accept some arguments from the command line. I'm trying to use argparse but can't get it to work properly.

I need it to work similar to the way the aws cli works e.g. aws s3 cp has it's own arguments, aws s3 ls, has it's own etc

ref: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/cp.html

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/ls.html

This is what I have but it always needs the mycmd option

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

parser.add_argument("mycmd", help="my test cmd")
parser.add_argument("-v", "--verbose", help="Verbose output", action="store_true")

args = parser.parse_args()

if args.mycmd:
    print(f"arg is mycmd")
if args.verbose:
    print("args v")
```

End result should be that mycmd1 has arguments xyz, mycmd2 has arguments abc etc and both can be ran from a single python file e.g. python3 somename.py mycmd1 -x ...

Comment: "but it always needs the mycmd option" – then why did you add it? I don't understand what you are asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [Python Click package](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/), which has explicit support for subcommands:

```
import click    

@click.group()    
def cli():    
    pass    

@cli.command()    
@click.option('--arg1')    
def mycmd1(arg1):    
    click.echo('My command 1')      
    if arg1:    
        click.echo(arg1)    

@cli.command()    
@click.option('--arg2')
def mycmd2(arg2):    
    click.echo('My command 2')    
    if arg2:    
        click.echo(arg2)      

if __name__ == '__main__':    
    cli()
```

Usage:

```
(~)$ python -m click-example --help     
Usage: click-example.py [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...

Options:
  --help  Show this message and exit.

Commands:
  mycmd1
  mycmd2
(~)$ python -m click-example mycmd1 --help
Usage: click-example.py mycmd1 [OPTIONS]

Options:
  --arg1 TEXT
  --help       Show this message and exit.
(~)$ python -m click-example mycmd2 --help
Usage: click-example.py mycmd2 [OPTIONS]

Options:
  --arg2 TEXT
  --help       Show this message and exit.
(~)$ python -m click-example mycmd2 --arg1 err
Usage: click-example.py mycmd2 [OPTIONS]
Try "click-example.py mycmd2 --help" for help.

Error: no such option: --arg1
(~)$ python -m click-example mycmd1 --arg1 hello
My command 1
hello
(~)$
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is completely valid. "mycmd" is just the name of your argument. I made some changes to your code to make it clearer:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

parser.add_argument("mycmd", help="my test cmd")
parser.add_argument("-v", "--verbose", help="Verbose output", action="store_true")

args = parser.parse_args()

if args.mycmd == "mycmd1":
    print(f"arg is mycmd1")
elif args.mycmd == "mycmd2":
    print(f"arg is mycmd2")
else:
    print("arg not allowed")
if args.verbose:
    print("args v")
```

On my machine:

```
$ python3 test.py mycmd1 -v
arg is mycmd1
args v
$ python3 test.py 12 -v
arg not allowed
args v
$ python3 test.py mycmd2 -v
arg is mycmd2
args v
```

Answer (score 0):

As per argparse documentation, if you do not state whether a positional argument is optional or not, it will be always needed.

You can state how many times you want your option to be used by `nargs`. In your case, add `nargs='?'` to make it optional (interpreted like in regex, `?` means "0 or 1").

See also [nargs in argparse's documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#nargs) - there are nice examples of optional input/output files positional arguments

---

In your case, you might find useful parent arg parsers. [Link to the part of the documentation about parents](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#parents) - just remember to read the part about handling colliding arguments (by default, both parsers will have `-h` option but you also might need some adjustments with your own arguments).

Answer (score 0):

c.py

```
import argparse
import sys



parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
                prog='c', description="Description: to do some task",
                epilog='Run c.py --help for more information')

subparser = parser.add_subparsers(title="Commands", help="commands")
mycmd_args = subparser.add_parser('mycmd', help='to dome some task',description="To do some task")
mycmd_args.add_argument("--arg1", "-a1", dest="argument1",help="provide argument")
mycmd_args.add_argument("--arg2", "-a2", dest="argument2",help="provide argument")

mycmd1_args = subparser.add_parser('mycmd1', help='to dome some task',description="To do some task")
mycmd1_args.add_argument("--arg1", "-a1", dest="argument1",help="provide argument")
mycmd1_args.add_argument("--arg2", "-a2", dest="argument2",help="provide argument")


if __name__=="__main__":
    args=parser.parse_args(sys.argv[1:])
    if len(sys.argv) <= 1:
        sys.argv.append("-h")

    elif sys.argv[1] == "mycmd":
        print("mycmd arguemnts")
        print(args.argument1)
        print(args.argument2)   
    elif sys.argv[1] == "mycmd1":
        print("mycmd1 arguemnts")
        print(args.argument1)
        print(args.argument2)
    else:
        sys.argv.append("-h")
```

output:

```
C:\Users\jt250054\Desktop>python c.py --help
usage: c [-h] {mycmd,mycmd1} ...

Description: to do some task

optional arguments:
  -h, --help      show this help message and exit

Commands:
  {mycmd,mycmd1}  commands
    mycmd         to dome some task
    mycmd1        to dome some task

Run c.py --help for more information

C:\Users\jt250054\Desktop>python c.py mycmd --help
usage: c mycmd [-h] [--arg1 ARGUMENT1] [--arg2 ARGUMENT2]

To do some task

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  --arg1 ARGUMENT1, -a1 ARGUMENT1
                        provide argument
  --arg2 ARGUMENT2, -a2 ARGUMENT2
                        provide argument

C:\Users\jt250054\Desktop>python c.py mycmd --arg1 argument1
mycmd arguemnts
argument1
None

C:\Users\jt250054\Desktop>python c.py mycmd --arg1 argument1 --arg2 arugment2
mycmd arguemnts
argument1
arugment2

C:\Users\jt250054\Desktop>
```